# PHPGrid and Event jqGridAddEditAfterSubmit - to manipulate data before saving

Tags: jqgrid-php, data-manipulation

relatively new to **PHPGrid** (basically a wrapper for jqGrid as far as I understand), I have a somewhat simple problem I do not seem to be able to find a solution for:

- before saving a row in a grid, set column C based on evaluations of columns A and B.  (It's not a formula, but an evaluation stating "if B <> NULL then C=B else C=A").

It may seem stupid to manipulate data like this, but it is a consequence of nightly batch updating and day-time entering of "override values".  (By the way, columns A and B are from different tables).

I've tried various techniques, such as using a trigger on an extra table (as triggers in mySQL can not update the table the trigger is defined for), but this has been deemed too slow (besides it a less-than-gifted way of doing things, right?).

Right now I am looking to use an event to manipulate the row before saving it.  It should be easy, right?

1. Is the event **jqGridAddEditAfterSubmit** the right one?
2. If so, which parameters does it take - there does not seem to be any documentation available?
3. Will it suffice to simple implement above mentioned manipulation and "leave it alone" to do the database updating ????

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated !

Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"as triggers in mySQL can not update the table the trigger is defined for", why is that? Did you check the table permission? You should upgrade your grant tables so that they contain the trigger-related privileges.

Comment: Hmmm - I may be completely wrong here, but I keep getting error code 1442.  Searching mySQL and error code 1442 gives a number of discussions on why mySQL does not allow updating of the triggering table.  In other words: I think you're wrong (but I may be mistaken) ???